# Disabled row in gridview, mouse scrolling does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, scroll

I need to disable rows if column status is different than 10.

I've got this code inside of my `gridview1_RowDataBound`

```
try
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[11].Text != "10")
    {
       e.Row.Enabled = false;
    }
}
catch { }
```

It does disable rows that I want but when I actually debug the project and i hover my mouse to disabled row, for some reason scrolling gets disabled. However if I move my mouse out of the gridview or line that is enabled, it works again.

Any idea how is that rendered and is there any available fix to this problem?

Comment: Try Disabling the controls of that row like (`((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Enabled = false;`). OR you can do it using jquery .

Comment: That does not work. Apparently it's the issue with Internet Explorer.